# If $f$ and $g$ tend to infinity, then $ \frac{f(x) + g^2(x)}{f^2(x) + g^6(x)} \to 0 $ at a neighborhood of $x \to a $

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\lim_{x \to a } f(x) = + \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to a } g(x) =- \infty$ then prove that $$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) + g^2(x)}{f^2(x) + g^6(x)} = 0 $$

Is it right to try squeezing the function between two others whose limit is 0?  I tried using the triangle inequality, and then I tried to compare with $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{|g^m(x)+f^n(x)|}}$ with lots of $m,n$ combinations.

Comment: Squeezing the function between to others that their limit is 0. Did I do it right?

Comment: Yes.  What other functions did you use?

Comment: The triangular inequality for the beginning and then I tried to compare $ | \frac{f+g^2}{f^2+g^6} |$ with $ | \frac{1}{g^m + f^n} | $ with lots of $m,n$ combinations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n$ be fixed. Let $x$ be in a neighbourhood of $a$ such that 
$$n < f(x)$$ and 
$$g(x)< -\sqrt[4]{n}$$ 
so $$n< g^4(x)$$
thus we have

$$nf(x) < f^2(x)$$
and 
$$n g^2(x)<g^6(x)$$

adding, 
$$n(f(x)+g^2(x)) < f^2(x)+g^6(x)$$ and so

$$\frac{f(x)+g^2(x)}{f^2(x)+g^6(x)}< \frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $H(x)$ be our function. If $x$ is large enough to ensure that $f(x)\ne 0$ and $g(x)\ne 0$,  then 
$$|H(x)|\le \frac{|f(x)|}{f^2(x)}+\frac{g^2(x)}{g^6(x)}.$$

Comment: This is the triangular inequality in the neighbourhood of $x \to a$

Comment: Nicely intuitive.

Comment: Yes, the triangle inequality was used. That lets us separate into two parts, $\frac{|f(x)|}{f^2(x)+g^6(x)}$ and a similar second part. We have nice control over both parts. For $\frac{|f(x)|}{f^2(x)+g^6(x)}$ is smaller than $\frac{|f(x)}{f^2(x)}$, with a similar result for the second part.